# How are duplicate type parameters handled?

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

I have a class looks like this.

```java
// just followed the T, U, V...
public class Some<T...., U....> {
}
```

And I need to add an instance method look like this.

```java
    // not a static method
    // just followed from BiFunction<T, U, R>.class
    protected <U, R> R apply(final BiFunction<T, U, R> function,
                             final U u) {

    }
```

The `T` of the method is same as the `T` of the class.
But the `U` of the method is not necessarily same as the `U` of the class.

Should I change one of those `U`?

In other words,

Are those two `U` same?

Comment: Are you asking whether you should use a different parameter name? Ideally, yes. I think the compiler will warn you if you hide the class parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No according to the scoping rules those `U` are not the same. The `U`of the `apply` method shadows the one from the class `Some`. To avoid confusion I would rename one of those `U`s.